# Module initialization in functional programing

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In a project, I use a module containing global (constant once initialized) stuffs that I use in the rest of the project. I choose to put them into a module to avoid a lot of arguments passing. The problem is that this module have to be initialized at run-time with the argument of the program execution.

How could this be done in a functional paradigm, in a langage like Haskell for example ?

Edit:

To be more precise, I code my project in an imperative language (Ada), that's why I can use a module containing variables initialized at run-time, and then used as global constants (with inlined getter). However, being interested in functional programming, I wonder how to obtain the same result in this paradigm; I mean to have light signatures all over the rest of the code (using global constant), module data localized in the data section of memory, even be able to initialize different "constants" of the module separately, etc.

Comment: well you read the arguments in `main` with [`getArgs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs) and pass them around - if you want to get fancy you can use Read/StateMonad(Transformers) etc. - what you cannot do of course is to use constant values in your module - for anything more you have to be more specific as this question is really to broad

Comment: Some functional languages (but not Haskell) offer first-class modules that can be initialized with dynamic bindings.

Comment: @Carsten You were right, I edited my post to have more specific questioning.

Comment: @dfeuer Can you please give an example, I would really like to take a look at these language.

Comment: @dfeuer Ok, I take a look at OCaml, thanks to make me discover this feature.

Comment: I first saw the feature in Moscow ML. I think it may also show up in Agda and possibly Racket, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

If the behavior of your program depends on the arguments used on the command line, there is simply no way to hide that fact -- it will have to appear in the types of your program's components. The simplest way is to write

```
data Options = {- ... -}

doMyProgram :: Options -> IO ()
myModule'sConstantA :: Options -> A
myModule'sConstantB :: Options -> B
```

giving `Options` as an argument to any operation or value which depends on it. Fancy designs often also define a custom monad `M` for the program that includes a `MonadReader Options M` instance to reduce the size of type signatures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you say, there is no way to make options global late initialized constant ? The problem with the monad Reader is that I don't really understand it very well, but the signature is even though longer, because it has to be in the returned type. And what about location of data in memory ? (I edited my post to be more accurate)

Comment: @olp I'm sorry, but even after you ask the same question with different words, the answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it's not *impossible* so much as *probably shouldn't be done*.

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO.Unsafe

firstArg :: String
firstArg = head $ unsafePerformIO getArgs
{-# NOINLINE firstArg #-}

main = putStrLn firstArg
```

Please note how many times the word "unsafe" appears in that six line snippet.

It's dirty and gross, but IMO, there are a few valid uses cases of this paradigm, and global constant initialization is one of them. I use it to load level files in my games, for example.